# Вывести элементы с ответа от сервера в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Вывести элементы с ответа от сервера. Приходит ответ от сервера.

```
    {
    "users": [
        {
            "id_lib": "53",
            "name": "Никита",
            "surname": "Шишин",
            "group": "ПИН-151",
            "date_of_taking": "2016-10-08",
            "lib_card": "098-769",
            "name_book": "Операционные системы - Флоренсов 2009 г."
        },
        {
            "id_lib": "54",
            "name": "Владислав",
            "surname": "Павлюк",
            "group": "ИВТ-152",
            "date_of_taking": "2017-07-09",
            "lib_card": "777-777",
            "name_book": "Основы теории управления"
        },
        {
            "id_lib": "55",
            "name": "Виктор",
            "surname": "Юрченко",
            "group": "ПИ-151",
            "date_of_taking": "2017-01-01",
            "lib_card": "000-000",
            "name_book": "Как закрыть 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

И надо мне записать эти данные в DataGridView. Как это сделать?

Вот я пытаюсь сделать, в string json лежит пришедшие эти данные. Но пишет json не содержит определения для Count и не видит мои переменные id_lib, name и тд.

```
    private void DataGridView(string json)
{
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    t.Columns.Add("ИД");
    t.Columns.Add("Имя");
    t.Columns.Add("Фамелия");
    t.Columns.Add("Группа");
    t.Columns.Add("Дата выдачи");
    t.Columns.Add("Номер билета");
    t.Columns.Add("Название книги");

    for (int i = 0; json.Count > i; i++)
    {
        t.Rows.Add(new object[] { json.id_lib[i], json.name[i], json.surname[i], json.group[i], json.date_of_taking[i], json.lib_card[i], json.name_book[i] });
        dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: "но ошибки выдает" - ??

Comment: пишет json не содержит определения для Count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У строки json свойство Count означает количество содержащихся в ней символов. Но Вы же работаете не с символами!

Вы действуете слишком поспешно. Для того, чтобы JSON-строку преобразовать в массив каких-то объектов, недостаточно просто взять и пробежаться по ней в цикле. Нужно выполнить следующие шаги:

1. Определить контракт (объяснить приложению, объекты какого типа будут передаваться), чтобы получить возможность работать с осмысленными данными.
   В вашем случае это контейнер однотипных объектов User.
2. Сформировать класс. В нашем случае:

   ```
   public class Rootobject
   {
       public User[] users { get; set; }
   }

   public class User
   {
       public string id_lib { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string surname { get; set; }
       public string group { get; set; }
       public string date_of_taking { get; set; }
       public string lib_card { get; set; }
       public string name_book { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Сгенерировать код класса самостоятельно вы можете, если используете Visual Studio, через меню *Правка -> Специальная вставка*. Передайте туда содержимое JSON из буфера обмена.

3. Выполнить десериализацию объекта (привести его из вида, удобного для передачи) в вид, удобный для работы программиста.
   [Как это делается, можно посмотреть здесь (вам нужен метод Deserialize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object)
4. Вывести объект(ы) для отображения.